# Create a batch sript that uses findstr and variables to map drive

Tags: batch-file, set, var, findstr, net-use

So I am trying to create batch script that does a `findstr` of two variables. I am reading from a specific file where I need the variables from.

The variables I need are

```
NetPath=
NetPathmed=
```

And my goal is to use the two variables to do a network map drive. In the first `findstr` I need everything after the `NetPath=` and in the second I need just a specific amount of data from the string. A normal NetPathMed looks like this

```
NetPathmed=\\**IPaddress**:C:\folder\file.
```

I just need the IP address

For example the batch I created looks like this

```
cd: C:\folder\
set var1="findstr 'NetPath=' file.ini"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in ("%var1%") do set net=%%a&set path=%%b

Set var2= "findstr 'NetPathMed' opsetup.ini"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims==/ " %%c in ("%var2%") do set net=%%c&set path=%%d &set net=%%e

net use var1(driveletter) \var2(IPaddress)\network folder /persistent:yes
```

Comment: Do **NOT** use a user-variable named **PATH**. It is a reserved name which specifies the sequence of directories to be searched for executables.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
cd C:\folder\
set var1='findstr "NetPath=" file.ini'
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in (%var1%) do set var1=%%b

Set var2='findstr "NetPathMed" opsetup.ini'
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=\:" %%c in (%var2%) do ECHO elements %var1% %%c %%d: /persistent:yes
```

Well - fixed a bit. Very difficult to tell where the elements you are extracting from your files actually are and which you wish to assemble into your command.

Made worse by your using 'NetPathMed`in your code but`NetPathmed`in the data line you have given. If you don't use the`/i`switch,`findstr` is case-sensitive.

Other errors:

`cd:` should not have a `:`.

The command within the parentheses of the `for /f` should be enclosed in **SINGLE** quotes. `FINDSTR` likes `"double quotes"`

I couldn't tell whether you wanted the data to be placed in `var1` and `var2` or what - an example of the relevant contents of the two files and the required command to be generated would have been helpful.

I chose to assign all of the text after the `=` in the selected line from the first file into `var1` (because that's what you said)

The first part in `%%a` is token1 = `NetPath` (not used) and the second token (*=the rest of the line) appears in the next metavariable (`%%b`)

Similarly, parsing the **EXACT DATA** that you posted, you are only using the second and third tokens

```
token1 is NetPathmed=
token2 is **IPaddress**
token3 is C
token 4 is \folder\file. I just need the IP address
```

Note that you specified `/` not `\`. Different animal. Chalk and cheese.

So - all you'd need to do is assemble the various elements `%var1%` `%%c` and `%%d` together with the fixed text you require, replace the `echo` with `net use` after testing and you should be off...